# fromEvent not fire when I put HTMLElement, and fire when I put Jquery Object

Tags: rxjs

[Code Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zy4kg7)

If I put `$('input')` as parameter of `fromEvent` it will fire when I call `$('input').trigger('input')`. But if I put `document.getElementsByTagName('input')` as parameter it will not fire. It will fire only when I type, but not fire when I call `$('input').trigger('input')`.
Can someone explain why?

Note: `$('input').on('input', _ => console.log)` will work in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because the ngOnInit hook is running before the view is built, so the document selector is querying before the element is there, but jquery selectors are actually async waiting for the document to be ready.

here's how you do it the angular way:

```
  @ViewChild('inp')
  input
  // use the after view init hook
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement, 'input') // angular way
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => {
          console.log("tap input");
        })
      )
      .subscribe(_ => {
        console.log("subscribe input");
      });
  }
```

in your html, add this:

```
<input type="text" #inp>
```

or the even better angular way (not using `fromEvent`)...

```
<input type="text" (input)="showMe($event)">
```

then in component just have this:

```
showMe(e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jfoc7d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: and what? If I type all works good in both cases. Only If i click it doesn't work. Also, the element is found in ngOnInit, check with console.log(document.getElementByTagName('input'))